# Script with searchCursor crashing arcmap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor

I was trying to make a script that counts the max lenght found in each field of a table with data in it, but it immediately crashes arcmap upon executing

I know there might be a tool available on the internet, but I need to learn how to do it myself

Parameter(0) is a table input

Parameter(1) is a multi select fields input from the table

Code :

```
#Created By: Gabriel Canto
#Date: Julho 2016

#Import modules
import arcpy

#Variables
table = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
fields = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1).split(";")
fieldnames = {}
stringfield = ""

#Creating the fields parameter string
for field in fields:
    fieldlenghts[field] = 0
    stringfield = stringfield + "'" + field + "',"

#Removing the last comma
stringfield = stringfield[:-1]


with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table,[stringfield]) as rows:
    for row in rows:
    for field in fields:
        try:
            s = str(row.getValue(field))
            if fieldlenghts[field] < len(row.getValue(field)):
                fieldlenghts[field] = len(row.getValue(field))
        except:
            arcpy.AddMessage("Field " + field + " can't be a string")


output = ""   
for field in fields:
    output = field + " : " + fieldlenghts[field] + " caracters\n"


arcpy.AddMessage(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the length of a field, you can use `arcpy.ListFields` which returns a list of field objects that contain information about the field (List Fields: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listfields.htm , Field Objects: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/field.htm ).

```
field_info = arcpy.ListFields(data)
for field in field_info:
    print field.name, 
    print field.length, 
    print field.type,
```

If you're trying to see the longest input in a field, you need to iterate through the rows, not the fields. Think of a search cursor like a list of tuples, like `[(field1, field2, field3), (field1, field2, field3)]`. If this is your `cursor`, when you iterate in a for loop `for row in cursor:` your variable `row` is equal to `(field1, field2, field3)`, so when you want to look at a specific field in a row, you reference the field's index value like `row[0]` which would return the value `field1` in this example.

So, to help rework your example,

```
import arcpy

table = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
## Automatically get your field names
fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(table)]

## We'll use a python dict to store the field name and the 
## length of the longest value
field_len_dict = {i:0 for i in fields}

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: ## Iterate through rows
        index = 0
        for field in row: ## iterate through each value of the row
            if field is not None:
                if len(field) > field_len_dict[fields[index]]:
                    field_len_dict[fields[index]] = len(field)
                    index +=1
                else:
                    index +=1
             else: index +=1

arcpy.AddMessage(field_len_dict)
```